# automatic page update appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, html

I have an application that uses Python appengine, there is a service that updates the status of users, if an admin person has a page open, I would need it to update in real time. I know that appengine has CRON and task queues, what would be the correct way to handle this? Should I set an update flag in the models that that triggers jscript?

Comment: Are you asking how to update the admin page in real time? Cron and task queues are both background processes, meant to operate on data rather than render a response.

Comment: I was thinking I might need to poll the data, clearly not a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview) can be used to send real-time(ish) data to clients, without the need of clients polling the server.